# Parsing nested dictionary with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a JSON object that I am Deserializing using Newtonsoft.Json into a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`

I want to parse it into a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<double, int>>` using LINQ however I am struggling to do this with the nested part.

For un-nested Dictionaries I am just using `.ToDictionary(k => double.Parse(k.Key), k => int.Parse(k.Value))`

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by JSON object? A JObject? Or just a string? Can you please post what you have so far so we can try it?

Comment: Would be something like : .ToDictionary(k => double.Parse(k.Key), l => l.ToDictionary(int.Parse(l.Value)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var input = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        input.Add("test1", new Dictionary<string, string>());
        input["test1"].Add("1.2", "3");

        var output = input.ToDictionary(
            x => x.Key, 
            x => x.Value.ToDictionary(
                y => double.Parse(y.Key), 
                y => int.Parse(y.Value)
            )
        );
```

should do the trick.